# How do I Import an Exisiting WP Project into Aptana 3?

Tags: ide

How do I import an existing Wordpress project into Aptana 3.04.2?

I installed the Wordpress bundle in Aptana. I'm on a Mac running MAMP. My operating system is Leopard. My project is located at Sites->mysite.

1. I clicked "Import Project"
2. Clicked "General"
3. Selected "Existing Projects into Workspace"
4. Clicked "Next"
5. Select root directory-- browsed to mysite (But, I got "No projects are found to import".

How do I import my project (without messing it up)? Should I use "Create Project" instead? If so, how do I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingo Muschenetz helped me out. This link provides the solution:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Importing+an+Existing+Project